# Error loading data in Rails from MySQL using LOCAL_INFILE setting

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I get this error when i try to load a .cvs file

> Mysql2::Error: The used command is not allowed with this MySQL version: load data local infile 'db/fixtures/devel_countries.csv'

I've checked the mysql server configuration and I have set `LOCAL_INFILE = 'ON'`

This is some data from my configuration:

- Mysql Server version: 5.5.16 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
- Ruby: 1.9.2p136 (2010-12-25 revision 30365) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
- Rails: 3.1.1

The command I use to execute this is:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute( "load data local infile 'db/fixtures/devel_regions.csv' into table regions fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"' lines terminated by '\n' (id, iso_code, name, country_id, created_at, updated_at);")
```

what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your MySQL command:

```
load data local infile 'db/fixtures/devel_regions.csv' 
into table regions 
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '\"' 
lines terminated by '\n' 
(id, iso_code, name, country_id, created_at, updated_at);
```

In general the command looks correct to me.

I notice that you include the `LOCAL` command as part of it. According to the docs:

> If LOCAL is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a full path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which the client program was started.

It may be that the app as you're trying to run it can't handle the `local` part of the command, though it looks like you're using it correctly.

The first thing I'd try is running the command from the database console and seeing how that works. You get that by running `bundle exec rails db`.

Comment: I execute the query in mysql and rails console and i get the same error, but i dont know how to execute it with bundle exec rails db.